# Do you know what font this is?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, sans-serif

Please can anyone help me. I have been searching for hours using all sorts of font finder applications and cannot figure out what this font is! Could anyone please help?

[image: Example of the font]

PS Additional logo example

[image]

Comment: Without doing any research, they look like a kind-of-squished Gill Sans Bold.

Comment: @Brendan You are right! It could be [Gill Sans Bold](http://origin.myfonts.net/116/fs/u/11/c0bf9f952d36c30e5aa82d15e6008e.gif). I'd post that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's definitely out of the [Gill Sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gill_Sans) family. It's closest to the Bold weight that I have locally. My guess is that there's some kind of manual alteration - it looks like it's horizontally squished a bit, and it could possibly be faux-bolded as well. However, there might be some bolder weight or condensed variant that I'm unaware of.

Here's the glyphs I'm looking at:

[image: Gill Sans Bold]

It's definitely the same `G` and the same `M`.

Comment: Yeah the `GM` is Gill Sans with a stroke applied (hence the flat-bottomed centre of the `M`), then squashed a little horizontally. The rest is various flavours of Gill Sans stretched or squashed. The `R` is another distinctive one

Answer (score 3):

Here's the full logo. The three words seem to be in the same font (regular and bold). The "GM" part is close to Gill Sans Bold but the letters are a little rounder ("C").

[image: GM Machinery Limited]

Comment: Well that's definitely Gill Sans.

Answer (score 2):

Closest match I could find after a lengthy search for "sans-serif bold" is **[Granby Elephant Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/redrooster/granby-elephant-pro/)**. The G is quite particular in this one, I thought it would be easier to locate. Your sample is not Granby, but it has a similar G:

[image]

[image]